# Separation of Variables: unique solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

For the simple differential equation:

With $g(t): \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, differentiable on its domain, that satisfies
$$tg'(t) = pg(t)$$

We may use separation of variables, $\int g'/g \, dg = \int p/t \,dt  \Rightarrow g(t)=t^pC.$ For some constant $C$.

---

**Q:** How do we know if the solution is unique, supposing we are given an initial condition $g(k) = a$.

---

*My thoughts for Q2* Suppose exist a solution where for some $k$ where $g(k) \not= 0 $, then from separation of variables we obtain solution $f(t) =t^p g(k)/k^p$. Then, 
$$ \big(\frac{g}{f} \big)' = \frac{g'}{f} - \frac{gf'}{f^2} = 0. $$
as $f$ satisfies equation and is nonzero. Hence $g(t) = C' f(t) \Rightarrow C' = 1 \Rightarrow g(t) = f(t) $ by substituting $t=p$. When $g(k)=0$ for all $k$, then $f(t) = 0$ too. So in this case separation of variables does indeed give unique solution. But there is a *big* problem with my proof:

The trick $(g/f)'$ doens't hold generally if $f$ is $0$ for some values. i.e. this only work because of how I designed the problem...I do not know how to prove *rigorously* in general.

---

EDIT: Corrected typos and simplified question.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You have set things up so that singular integrals appear and now you have to decide how to interpret them. If you take Cauchys principle value then $\int dt/t=\ln|t|$ and from there you can get the solution for negative $t$ $$g=-Cp^{|t|}$$ which satisfies your ODE

Comment: Technically this is a [DAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation), not a DE. Perhaps knowing this will help you find the relevant information.